# Proper approach for image recognition of ~1000 symbols

Tags: machine-learning, classification, image-processing, image-segmentation

We have a dataset of black symbols in grey squares (like attached below).
The symbols are various letters (arabic, greek) as well as numbers in many distinct fonts; altogether ~1000 different images.

[image]

We need to build an image recognition model (recognises each of the squares independently, so there are as many classes as there are images). This seems like an enormous task, I would like to know what would be the most suitable approach?

#### Edit

Let me summarise and clarify what we resolved in the discussion below the post:

- each image is an unique label; there are exactly as many unique labels as images
- I need to have a system which recognises these exact 1000 images. Noting more. I am new to image recognition therefore I am wondering what kind of model/algorithm should I apply to such exact problem.
- However, new examples may indeed come, for example improperly cropped squares, or re-sized images (smaller resolution).
- In an extreme case someone might even provide a very improperly cropped square which would include some background around it. The bg may be anything, no constraints. In such case - should I recognize the borders of the squares first and then proceed (how?)

#### Edit2

After a discussion under [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/548651/174383) I conclude that the question is still open and I cannot accept a solution yet. It seems that proposed CNN would require ~6000 examples per image, which in my case of 1000 symbols is not realistic. That is why I would especially like to learn how should I proceed in this exact dataset (approach? model? algorithm?)

Comment: Are the images labeled?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by "proper". According to Chaitin circa 1960's, I also cannot provide a proof that any given model is the best model. Rather, I recommend you look into classification with convolutional neural networks (CNNs). CNN's learn translationally invariant patterns by convolving trainable filters.

Comment: @Sycorax: yes, each image has a unique label and this label should be learned

Comment: When you say "unique" label, do you mean that if you have 5 images of the letter A, each has a different label (5 labels in total)? Or do you mean that all images of the letter A are labeled "A"?

Comment: @Galen: Proper, meaning, the most reasonable method to address such a problem, given the specifics of the example I provided. CNN could be one way but it requires a huge training set whereas we just have these 1000 images that should be recognized.

Comment: @Sycorax: 5 different labels

Comment: So you have 1000 images and 1000 labels, and no label is applied to more than 1 image?

Comment: @Sycorax: Correct.

Comment: @maciek Do you have a test set? Or do you only have training data?

Comment: There is no training/testing data. There is just the set of 1000 images that need to be recognized. Whether I divide it or not its up to me but the bottom line is that all of them need to be learned correctly.

Comment: @maciek Okay. Will there be new examples presented to the model later, or is this model intended to 'memorize'/compress this n=1000 dataset only?

Comment: @Galen: I think I would like to know what your opinion would be in both of these cases: (1: no new data) and (2: new examples incoming). But the original question was about (1)

Comment: The reason this is confusing is that it doesn't seem to be a statistical question. If there's no requirement for generalization, then one solution is to parse the images into an array and then for each image in your data set, subtract. The training example with the smallest difference is the label. Is this approach unsuitable? Why or why not?

Comment: @maciek In case (1) I agree with Sycorax: Simply computing the nearest neighbours would be sufficient. However, you could attempt to train a model that is smaller than storing all of the original images...

In case (2) you will encounter issues with generalization error if the new examples are not highly similar to the training examples.

Comment: @Galen: OK, the point is that new examples might be incoming in different resolution or maybe cropped a little improperly...  so slight non-similarities may appear...

Comment: @maciek  Cropping issues can be helped by considering translational invariance, motivating the use of CNN's. You could resize the images and then simply find out if the error rates are acceptable. As I mentioned about Chaitin's work, there will exist no proof that you have the best model. Rather you must rely on testing error.

Comment: @maciek With some coding, it sounds like you could create a training and test dataset by creating cropping issues and changes in resolution in new images created from your original data set.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! One more question: What if the square would be on some colorful background? I would like to extract the square first... But I don't know how to recognize borders...

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your post to include the additional details that you've outlined in these comments.

Comment: @Sycorax: OK, Done, waiting for a review.

Answer (score 2):

## You need to collect relevant data.

The 1000 symbols that you have right now are not representative of the task that you want to achieve. You have 1000 symbols that are "perfect" -- they're centered in the square, they're the same size, the backgrounds are uniform gray, they're all the same resolution.

But the problem you're trying to solve isn't about how to label these perfect images; it's about how to address the cases of imperfect images.

> - However, new examples may indeed come, for example improperly cropped squares, or re-sized images (smaller resolution).
> - In an extreme case someone might even provide a very improperly cropped square which would include some background around it. The bg may be anything, no constraints. In such case - should I recognize the borders of the squares first and then proceed (how?)

What you need to do is collect examples of the kinds of images that you will be classifying -- the ones with weird backgrounds, improper cropping, are resized, etc.

One shortcut to collect this kind of data is to apply transformations to your perfect images -- translate the character, make the background look like one of the imperfect backgrounds, etc. But this is only a viable strategy insofar as the transformations that you apply are relevant to the transformations you'll encounter when using the model. This is why data collection is important -- you won't know about the transformations that you don't know about, so you'll need to collect examples.

---

After you've collected data, this seems like a standard character recognition task. One common approach is to use convolutional neural networks, but there are many others.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; I would like to ask two more things before I accept this: (1) I know about CNN since they are the hottest topic right now, but could you please provide some bullet points with other approaches which you think would be suitable here? (2) How much examples do you think I should collect per 1 image? Does this number depend on the total number of images (1000)?

Comment: Alternative strategies use some feature extraction method (HOG, SIFT) to transform images into fixed-length vectors and then apply a tabular method (random forest, SVM, xgboost, etc).

Comment: Would you have a comment on (2)?

Comment: MNIST is a standard toy problem using handwritten digits; it has 60,000 training images total with 10 equal classes. But it is one of the smaller image datasets.

Comment: Well, that is my problem then; 60,000/10 = 6000 examples per class. This is not realistic for my situation. That is why I ask what would be a proper approach/model in this particular case of 1000 symbols/classes

Comment: My answer explains why your data collection strategy is not suitable for the problem that you want to solve.

Comment: OK, thank you very much then; I have added one more edit to the question accordingly.

Comment: My comment about the size of MNIST digits is not specific to CNNs. Indeed, many of the early results published using MNIST digits were not CNNs. The problem you face is about how to generalize to noisy data; to do that, you'll need to train a model on noisy data. There's no way to escape the necessity of data collection in a statistical project. Maybe the data can be programmatically generated, or maybe not, but you need data that exemplifies to the problem you want to solve. Based on your own description, you don't have suitable data.